# Jetty from a standard Java SE app

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty

I'd like to use Jetty and it's web sockets API in a plain old java SE app. I have followed a few good tutorials but have gotten stuck. I am trying to build using eclipse and I am not using maven. I am getting stuck with this compilation error:

```
The type javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

When I have this code for the server:

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.servlet.WebSocketServletFactory;

public class MyServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Server server = new Server(8080);
        WebSocketHandler wsHandler = new WebSocketHandler() {
            @Override
            public void configure(WebSocketServletFactory factory) {
                factory.register(MySocket.class);
            }
        };
        server.setHandler(wsHandler);
        server.start();
        server.join();
   }
}
```

I am developing using eclipse (and not maven or any other tool) and I have added what I think are the necessary .jar files to the project from the Jetty download:

```
javax.websocket-api-1.0.jar
websocket-api-9.2.8.v20150217.jar
websocket-server-9.2.8.v20150217.jar
websocket-servlet-9.2.8.v20150217.jar
jetty-server-9.2.8.v20150217.jar
jetty-servlet-9.2.8.v20150217.jar
```

Can someone explain the setup process for using Jetty in eclipse in a non-EE app without maven?

Comment: Update your question to include the list of jar files you are using with your application.  Since you are not using a build tool (this is highly recommended!!) you will have to manage the list of jar files manually, lets start with what you have and work from there.

Comment: You need at least javax.servlet-api-3.0.jar

Answer (score 2):

You need to add servlet-api-3.1.0.jar that fix your error: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0

This link, with explanation how to use Jetty without maven, may be helpful https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Jetty_HelloWorld

Answer (score 1):

1. Use [mavenrepository.com](http://mavenrepository.com) to find out the dependencies of your libs.

For example:

`http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-server/9.2.8.v20150217`

(you missed the lib 'javax.servlet v3.1.0')

2. Or use [grepcode.com](http://grepcode.com/) to search for which lib should the 'cannot be resolved' class in.